# Компилятор потерял тип?

Tags: c#

Причем подсказка отображает тип:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... но компиляция вызывает ошибку. И даже "!" не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
public struct SOptions<T> where T : notnull {
  public static SOptions<T> Default => new();
  public int SomeProperty = 123;
}

public class Options<T> where T : notnull {
  public int SomeProperty { get; private set; } = 0;

  public Options(SOptions<T> options) => SetOptions_1(options);

  public void SetOptions_1(SOptions<T>? options) {
    options ??= SOptions<T>.Default;
    // Строка ниже вызывает ошибку, код не компилируется
    // error CS1061
    SomeProperty = options!.SomeProperty;
  }

  // ... Такой вариант ошибок не вызывает.
  public void SetOptions_2() {
    var options = SOptions<T>.Default;
    SomeProperty = options.SomeProperty;
  }

  // ... С этим тоже работает.
  public void SetOptions_3(SOptions<T>? options) {
    options ??= SOptions<T>.Default;
    SomeProperty = ((SOptions<T>)options).SomeProperty;
  }
}
```

[dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cEgz0O)

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам там нужно `!.` ?

Comment: Вы используете `Nullable<SOptions<T>>`. Если вы хотите получить нужное свойство необходимо использовать синтаксис `options.Value.SomeProperty`. Почитайте про `Nullable` вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @AlAvenger Я эту страницу по диагонали читал, спасибо. Там ведь и подсказки наличия свойств `options.HasValue` есть после точки, на что я не обратил внимания.

Comment: @CrazyElf Конечно не нужно. Это был "крик о помощи" компилятору, но он со мной не разговаривает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте не nullable локальную переменную

```
public void SetOptions_1(SOptions<T>? options)
{
    SOptions<T> opt = options ?? SOptions<T>.Default;
    SomeProperty = opt.SomeProperty;
}
```

Или не используйте

```
public void SetOptions_1(SOptions<T>? options)
{
    if (options.HasValue)
    {
        SomeProperty = options.Value.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Моей ошибкой было, что `struct` это значение, а не ссылочный тип. И тонкость различий NULL в типах значений и ссылок я до сего момента не замечал.

Comment: Но первый вариант лучше все же избегать, мы получим ненужное копирование. И остановиться на таком `= foo.HasValue ? foo.Value.Property : Default`